# Configuring Docker host in jenkins

Tags: ubuntu, docker, jenkins

I have installed Jenkins ver. 2.73.3 in Ubuntu 17.10
Same machine also has Docker version 17.09.0-ce.

I also added the following line in /etc/default/docker file
DOCKER_OPTS="docker -H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock"

```
cat /etc/default/docker
# Docker Upstart and SysVinit configuration file

#
# THIS FILE DOES NOT APPLY TO SYSTEMD
#
#   Please see the documentation for "systemd drop-ins":
#   https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/
#

# Customize location of Docker binary (especially for development testing).
#DOCKERD="/usr/local/bin/dockerd"

# Use DOCKER_OPTS to modify the daemon startup options.
#DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4"

DOCKER_OPTS="docker -H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock"

# If you need Docker to use an HTTP proxy, it can also be specified here.
#export http_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:3128/"

# This is also a handy place to tweak where Docker's temporary files go.
#export DOCKER_TMPDIR="/mnt/bigdrive/docker-tmp"

----------------------------------

sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo service docker restart
```

After this in the Jenkins Configure page for Docker cloud. I get the following error. Please see the attached screenshot
[image]

Comment: make sure docker is listening on the port by running `netstat -tunlp`. Also check `systemctl status docker.service`.

Comment: ● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-11-24 11:06:33 IST; 3min 3s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 28272 (dockerd)
    Tasks: 22
   Memory: 18.3M
      CPU: 762ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           ├─28272 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://
           └─28289 docker-containerd -l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your case docker daemon  is not considering the /etc/default/docker file, you can check my making some syntax error in above file.
else run this cmd and do a test once.
dockerd -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 &

before firing command stop all the docker service and kill containers if any

Comment: running the command gives the error [1] 27975
user1:~$ `docker daemon` is not supported on Linux. Please run `dockerd` directly. How do you get the docker daemon running.

Comment: dockerd -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375

Comment: sudo dockerd -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 
Error starting daemon: pid file found, ensure docker is not running or delete /var/run/docker.pid
user1:~$ sudo rm /var/run/docker.pid
user1:~$ sudo dockerd -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 
WARN[] [!] DON'T BIND ON ANY IP ADDRESS WITHOUT setting --tlsverify IF YOU DON'T KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING [!] 
INFO  libcontainerd: previous instance of containerd still alive (28793) 
Error starting daemon: error while opening volume store metadata database: timeout

Comment: as it says containers are still runing, make sure docker is completely stoped and kiil all container ( docker ps -a ). dockerd -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375

Comment: thank you so much it worked. i was not stopping the docker. that was the issue. can you just update the answer. maybe its an obvious thing what you told me, but i wasted much time, it can be of help to others. and i will accept it as the correct answer.